# Localized phone number formatting

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, localization, formatting

I've looked into `NSFormatter`, `NSNumberFormatter`, and the other formatting classes, but can't find a build into solution. I need to format phone numbers depending on the country code.

For instance, for US, I get a string such as `+16313938888` which I need to format to look like `+1(631)393-8888`. The problem is I need to do this for all formats. Netherlands, I receive a string `+31641234567` which will be `+31(6)41 23 45 67` (something like that).

Hardcoding for 200+ countries is too tedious and I really don't know all the format rules. Is there something in the docs I'm overlooking or does anyone know of an open source class that manages this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat for an iOS specific solution.

Comment: It doesn't require a private framework. It requires a copy of a data file. I know of two apps in the App Store using it and each has had several updates over the years with no issues.

Comment: @JimThio now this is not matching with ios 8 contact format please give any update

Comment: @rmaddy  now this is not matching with ios 8 contact format please give any update. This is great lib upto ios 7 But not matching wiht ios 8 . Please helo

Answer (score 3):

Try this Google solution - https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS
They have ports for C++, Java, Objective-C and others.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately iOS does not have any public APIs for this. You can try to integrate [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) that is a complete implementation for parsing and formatting international phone numbers. It has a C++ version so theoretically you can cross-link with it.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to hard-code all of the various country formats.  There are typically 3-5 formats per country.  Instead, use a format database (such as a plist) and write code to format the number based on the given country code.

A good international format property list 'UIPhoneFormats.plist' can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/iphone-patch/source/browse/trunk/bgfix/UIKit.framework/PhoneFormats/UIPhoneFormats.plist?r=7

In that list, '$' allows any character, '#' must be a number, and the '(space) ', '(', ')' and '-' are inserted between numbers.  Non-numeric characters typed by the user hint to the desired format.

I've shared my phone number formatter class, inspired by Ahmed Abdelkader's work, at https://github.com/lathamglobal/iOS-Phone-Number-Formatter . It is a very small, single-class international phone number formatter that uses the plist just mentioned.

Comment: Your direct link to that UIPhoneFormats.plist file doesn't work any more, but I've found it in the source anyway. It is incomplete as many countries are missing, and is mostly just wrong for countries that are included.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS. It uses JSON data from Google's libphonenumber, then converts it to ObjC code for faster access at run-time. So far so good. Google's database is the most comprehensive and up to date among the openly available ones as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
    let phoneNumber : CNPhoneNumber
    let digits = phoneNumber.performSelector("digits").takeRetainedValue() as! String
```

It gives you directly the string, without formatting, with the phone number. However if the number is saved with international prefix, you will have it also in the resulted string.

Comment: Keep in mind `CNPhoneNumber`, is available for iOS9 above.