# Putting in Parentheses While Typing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localized phone number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407726/localized-phone-number-formatting)

I am trying to make it to where you type in a phone number and **while typing**, it realizes that there are so many characters and adds in parentheses: (xxx)xxx-xxxx. I have looked on Stack Overflow for any similar answers to my problem and I came along with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441315/how-to-set-the-textfield-format-as-decimal-while-typing).

However, I can't use conversions to decimal form to solve my issue but have gained more knowledge in the fact that I probably should use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:withString:` method. I am also going to be needing to add in the hyphen as well in the phone number but figured if I can do it for one I can do it for the other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: In all honesty, don't bother.  There are hundreds of different ways of formatting telephone numbers.  Some countries have more than one.  Just accept strings of digits. and spend your energy on the bits of your application that matter.

Comment: @JeremyP Thank you for your suggestion! Although I am probably considering your idea as my solution, it is still true that the answer below that was provided works for the standard number.

Comment: Hi, yes the answer given does answer your question and deserves the accept but it would fail for a non US number.  There really is no such thing as a standard telephone number format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField.text.length == 0)
     textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length == 4)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@) ",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length == 9)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length > 13)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle most phone formats.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. The only problem is with the number pad when you tell it to delete it does not. Simple fix though just get rid of the if (textField.text.length > 13). Thanks a million!

Comment: @rmaddy, it wasn't meant to, it was just a quick modification of an answer I gave to another question, that I hope will get the op started.

Comment: @Zack, what problem are you talking about?

Comment: its not working when use try to edit number